# xtable for arrays

Tags: r, plyr, sweave, xtable, knitr

I'm trying to use xtable for 3-dimensional array. My minimal example is

```
Test <- 
structure(1:8, .Dim = c(2L, 2L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(c("A1", 
"A2"), c("B1", "B2"), c("C1", "C2")))

library(plyr)
library(xtable)

a_ply(.data=Test, .margins=3, function(i) {
  xtable(x = Test[, , i])
      }
)
```

This produces the following error:

```
  Error in xtable(x = Test[, , i]) : subscript out of bounds
```

I'd appreciate if you give me some pointers to resolve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is the expected result?

Comment: I want to print `Test[ , ,1]` and `Test[ , , 2]` in this simple case through `a_ply`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`a_ply` doesn't return anything so hopefully your function saves these or something along those lines.  the i you're passing to the function is the subset of your array based on the margins you provide.  so you're sending it the 2x2 array C1 then the 2x2 array C2:

```
a_ply(Test, 3, function(i) {print(i); print('-----')})
```

so indexing into your `Test` array with `i` doesn't make sense.

why not just:

```
apply(Test, 3, xtable)
```

or using plyr:

```
alply(Test, 3, xtable)
```

For knitr:

```
a_ply(Test, 3, function(i) print(xtable(i)))
```

Comment: Almost. They want to include the output using **knitr** so they probably want their function to be `function(x) {print(xtable(x))}` and then use `a_ply` to suppress all other output.

Comment: @Justin: I'd appreciate if you let me know how to include the name of third dimension in the caption of these tables. Like `C1` in the first table's caption and `C2` in the second table's caption. Thanks

Comment: `sapply(dimnames(Test)[[3]], function(i) {print(xtable(Test[,,i], caption=i)); return(NULL)})`  I don't know `knitr` well, but that makes the latex properly.

Comment: @Justin: Thanks again for your help. Your given code works fine except giving extra stuff like this `$C1 NULL`. I wonder how to get rid of this. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is an old thread, but I had a similar issue on a current project.  I wanted an HTML table output with the caption labelled using the name of the 3rd dim of my array.

The problem was overcome by using my array differently.  This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16674755)  led me to my solution.

```
x <- 1:dim(Test)[3]
l_ply(x, 
      function(i) cat(print(
                           xtable(Test[,,i],
                                  caption = paste("Heading ",
                                          dimnames(Test)[[3]][i],
                                          sep = "")),
                           type = "html", caption.placement = "top"), 
                         file = "Test.html",
                         append = TRUE))
```