# linux - running system command in R and then writing output to a file

Tags: linux, r, system

I have R code as below. Below code resides in a file called 'iot.R'. I am executing it in Linux.

I want to print content of variable 'fileinformation' to a file mentioned by file=fileConn...
I thought that the 3rd line will solve the issue, but it is not giving the required output :(

```
   fileinformation = system(paste("file", filenames[1]))
    #print(fileinformation)
    cat(print(fileinformation),"\r\n","\r\n", file=fileConn)
```

When I run the file, i get below result. It prints to my screen, rather than writing to the file :(

```
> source('iot.R')
CH7Data_20130401T135010.csv: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
[1] 0
```

--------------------update1

I also tried below command, but didnt get the expected rsult

```
cat(capture.output(fileinformation),"\r\n","\r\n", file=fileConn)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `intern` argument to `TRUE` in your call to `system`. For instance:

```
    fileinformation<-system("file cinzia_2.gif",intern=TRUE)
    fileinformation
    #[1] "cinzia_2.gif: GIF image data, version 89a, 640 x 640"
```

Of course I tried a file on my pc. Setting `intern` to `TRUE` the return value of `system` becomes the console output of the command. Then, when you call `cat`, you don't need to enclose `fileinformation` into `print`, but a simple `cat(fileinformation,"\r\n","\r\n", file=fileConn)` will suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Just a comment as I dont have enough rep to comment in the normal way. but cant you use

```
write.table
```

to save the output to a file? It may be easier?

Comment: i am writing a lot of other data to file=fileConn..aand write.table will create a different table...it wont add to fileConn :(

Comment: in that case write() instead of print with append=TRUE?

Comment: something like: write(fileinformation,file=fileConn,append=TRUE)? its hard to comment without reproducible code.

Comment: the following may also be of use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16658866/writing-variables-to-a-file-with-writelines

Comment: same thing...it didnt help. It printed 0 to the actual file and printed output of the command to the screen